# 'residual_metric' error in RANSACRegressor model in python

Tags: python, model, regression

I want to do a regression model and with RANSACRegressor i want to delete abnormal value,this is my code:

from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor

ransac = RANSACRegressor(

LinearRegression(),

max_trials=50,

min_samples=8,

residual_metric= lambda x: np.sum(np.abs(X), axis=1),

residual_threshold=5.0,

random_state=0)

ransac.fit(X, Y)

And then i have this error after i run the program:

"**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'residual_metric"

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5497 
This can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is because **residual_metric** is removed in new version and **loss** is added for the same purpose.

For more detail on **loss**: 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html

For more details on this movement: 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5497

Check Example 57, here https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/75200/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor